# Ubuntu 16.04 External Display Stopped Working (Black)

Tags: 16.04, multiple-monitors, display, external-monitor

I've been running Ubuntu on my laptop for a couple of years and upgraded to 16.04 several months ago with no problems.  I go out on site regularly so often plug my laptop into external screens through HDMI as well as using an VGA adapter to connect to projectors.

I've never had a problem with the 2nd screen until yesterday.  When I plug in a monitor, whether directly (HDMI) or via the VGA adapter dongle Ubuntu recognizes it but nothing displays.

My displays shows 2 screens `"Build in display"` and `"Goldstar company 23"` just like it always has and I've tried switching primary, secondary and mirror to no avail.  I've also tried powering up with it plugged in, not plugged in, different monitors, different cables, checking to see if something in the BIOS has been disabled and tried pressing the various monitor buttons to flips between on off external mirror etc.

I've even just reinstalled Ubuntu 16.04 again to see if something had gone adrift in the background and I get the same thing.

Thanks for your help!

xrandr shows:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected primary 1280x720+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 293mm x 164mm
   1366x768      60.00 +
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x720      60.00* 
   1024x768      60.00  
   1024x576      60.00  
   960x540       60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   864x486       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x405       60.00  
   680x384       60.00  
   640x360       60.00  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 510mm x 290mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1152x864      59.97  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

lspci shows

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 05)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 (rev c4)
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this has been a while so thank you to everyone who tried to help.  It turned out it was a hardware problem with the HDMI socket.  Nothing to do with Ubuntu!

Answer (score 0):

Mine does the same thing, except the exturnal monitor turns itself off (saying no input) ONLY after I have logged in. Until then it displays normally. 
If I open monitor settings to sort the problem, I can make the laptop detect the screen and configure it. However, on pressing Apply, both screens go black and do not restore settings as they should after the 30 second "keep this configuration?" dialogue.
The problem became apparent the second time I logged in. I updated Ubuntu 2 days ago

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on an Asus N56V.

**edit**
I fixed mine just now by switching my graphics driver to "using X.Org X Server..."

Comment: This is not the same issue, my laptop has previously been fine and I've made no changes, both screens DO NOT go black, they are both correctly recognised but switching to either mirror or extend does nothing to my laptop screen, just the external monitor.

Comment: Understood, try to be clearer with your descriptions. Hope things work out

Answer (score 0):

Boot with "Advanced options for Ubuntu" and select another kernel (old kernel).

--